# Why am I getting a null pointer exception in my hibernate get method?

Tags: hibernate

```
// This is my pojo class

package com.kittu.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Rollno;
    private String Name;

    public int getRollno() {
        return Rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(int Rollno) {
        this.Rollno = Rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }       
}

//**Main class**

package com.kittu.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
       User u1=new User();
       u1.setName("gontu");

       Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
       cfg = cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
       Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();

       u1 = (User)session.get(User.class,1);

       System.out.println("student object having name as" +u1.getName());

       session.getTransaction().commit();
       session.close();
       sessionFactory.close();
   }
}
```

// **I have created database name user in mysql db**

**Error**

> ```
> run:
> Aug 12, 2017 10:42:18 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
> INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
> Aug 12, 2017 10:42:18 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
> INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
> Aug 12, 2017 10:42:18 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
> INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
> Aug 12, 2017 10:42:18 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver
> ```
>
> resolveEntity
>       WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use
>   namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration
>   instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at
>   any time.
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:19 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>   
>       INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure
>       WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:19 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/hibernate_tutorials]
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator
>       INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:20 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>   
>       INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:20 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect 
>       INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:21 AM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
>       INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
>       Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
>       Hibernate: drop table if exists User
>       Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
>       Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
>       Hibernate: create table User (Rollno integer not null, Name varchar(255), primary key (Rollno))
>       Aug 12, 2017 10:42:24 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl
>   applyImportSources
>       INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@623e088f'
>       Hibernate: select user0_.Rollno as Rollno1_0_0_, user0_.Name as Name2_0_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.Rollno=?
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.kittu.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:24)
>       BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 14 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Session.get() always returns null if the value doesn't exists in the database..in your case if the user with id=1 doesn't exists it will return null..also if the user exists with id=1 and name as null in db, then also you will get null pointer exception while doing `System.out.println("student object having name as" +u1.getName());`

Comment: Yes. It seems there is no data in the database. And The user is trying to retrieve the object before saving it.